# problem with ajax on update .net Framework 2.0 to .net framework 3.5 from VS 2008

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, ajax.net

I get a java script error on Internet Explorer when changing the index of a
drop down list control inside a form.
the error is: __EVENTTARGET is null or is not an object
The code is auto generated by the framework library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in a  tag of the html that didn't has close tag.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MS Ajax? I had the same problem with VS 2008 so I downloaded the latest version of Ajax framework and Ajax Control Tookit and then it seemed to be working fine.

Comment: Important information: that error occurs only when  EnablePartialRendering="true"